# r for loop files and variables in another file

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a list of files wanted to `for` loop to do the calculation but there is a value needed to include in another file. I don't know how to for loop in this situation.

input 1:

```
1.file.csv
2.file.csv
3.file.csv
4.file.csv
5.file.csv
.
.
.
50.file.csv
```

input 2:

```
Value
1. 0.765
2. 0.00031
3. 0.434
4. 0.001
5. 0.004
.
.
.
50. 0.623
```

I want to for loop like this but don't know how to do in "input_2" value:

```
for i in seq(1:50) {
    input_1 <- read.table(i, header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)
    function(x)(file = input_1,  mean = input_2)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems straightforward.  Would this work:

```
mn.vals  <- read.table(input_2)
out.vals <- vector(length=50)
for(i in 1:50){
  input_1     <- read.csv(file=paste0("file", i, ".csv"), header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)
  out.vals[i] <- <some function taking file=input_1,  mean=mn.vals[i]> 
} 
out.vals
```